# "slice indices must be integers" error when splitting a data array

Tags: python, list, runtime-error

Could you help me with this problem. x is already an integer. But I am getting this problem , If I use 90 instead of x , code runs but with x variable doesn't work.

```
split_ratio=[3,1,1]
x=split_ratio[0]/sum(split_ratio)*data.shape[0]
print(x)
print(data[0:x,:])
```

Output ;

```
90.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-0e56a1aca0a0> in <module>()
      2 x=split_ratio[0]/sum(split_ratio)*data.shape[0]
      3 print(x)
----> 4 print(data[0:x,:])

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Comment: Why is there a ```,```. I think that is the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you do division by `/`, it always returns a *float* and not an *integer*, although the answer may be an integer (with nothing after decimal points).
To fix this, there are two ways, one is to use the `int()` function and the other is to use floor division `//`.

So, you can either do

```
x=int(split_ratio[0]/sum(split_ratio)*data.shape[0])
```

or

```
x=split_ratio[0]//sum(split_ratio)*data.shape[0]
```

Now, when you will do `print(x)` the output will be `90` and not `90.0` as `90.0` meant that it was a float and `90` means that now it is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the output that the number is a floating point number(`90.0`) and not an integer(`90`). Just convert to `int` like -

```py
x=int(split_ratio[0]/sum(split_ratio)*data.shape[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

When splicing a string an iterable such as a list, you cannot use floats.
Take the below code as an example of what not to do

---

**Example**

```
data = 'hello there'
#bad is a float since 4/3 1.333
bad = 4/3
#here bad is used as the end (`indexing[start:end:step]`). 
indexIt = data[0:bad:1]
```

as a result of using a float where an integer should be

**Result**

> TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method

---

A workaround to this would be to surround `bad`'s value in `int()` which should convert `1.333 to 1` (float to int)

**solution**

```
data = 'hello there'
bad = int(4/3)
indexIt = data[0:bad:1]
print(indexIt)
```

**Result**

```
"h"
```

So with this considered, your code should look something like

```
split_ratio=[3,1,1]
x=split_ratio[0]/sum(split_ratio)*data.shape[0]
print(x)
print(data[0:x:])
```

#Note: the comma after `x` when indexing should be removed.